# How can I access information from a database in Firebase in React Native and display it within a <Text>?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to read data from a realtim database in firebase but I can not get this information to be rendered in a **Text** component. I can only show the information of the object by **console.log** and decompose it but in the render of the screen the information is not shown.

```
class UserProfileScreen extends Component<Props> {

state = {
 dataUser : []
}

componentDidMount(){
const { uid } = firebaseAuth.currentUser
this.getUserRef().child(uid).once('value',function(snapshot){
 dataUser = snapshot.val()
  console.log(dataUser.username)
 })
}

getUserRef = () => {
  return firebaseDatabase.ref('users')
}

render(){
 const {dataUser} = this.state
 return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>{dataUser.username}</Text>
  </View>
  )
 }
}
```

Object obtained from the database displayed by console:
[image: Object obtained from the database displayed by console],

Android Emulator:
[image: Android Emulator]

What I can be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the state property once the value has been retrieved:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = { dataUser: {} };
}

componentDidMount(){
  ...
  this.getUserRef().child(uid).once('value',function(snapshot){
    dataUser = snapshot.val()
    this.setState({
      dataUser: dataUser // es5
      dataUser // es6 
    });
  });
  ...
}
```

[Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Thank you very much: D **worked**, you have all the reason and more with the link of the documentation I could understand and now it works perfect.